# FsUnit showing two identical expected values for F# types

Tags: .net, f#, nunit-3.0, fsunit

The two tests below fail, of course.  But why do the error messages show two identical expected values?  Is there a way of only showing one?

`myTest` returns `Expected: <B> or <B>  But was:  <A>`

`myTest2` returns `Expected: <{ N = 2 }> or <{ N = 2 }>  But was:  <{ N = 1 }>`

This works as expected (e.g. `Expected: <B>  But was:  <A>`) when using plain NUnit instead.

This gets pretty nasty when working with more complicated types, of course.

Tests.cs:

```
namespace Blah

open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework

module Tests =

    type MyDU = A | B

    type MyRecord = { N: int }

    [<Test>]
    let myTest ()=
        A |> should equal B

    [<Test>]
    let myTest2 ()=
        { N = 1 } |> should equal { N = 2 }
```

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Tests.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FsUnit" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

Comment: I have no experience with FsUnit, but it looks like you're not following the instructions here: https://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/

Comment: @BentTranberg Could you be more specific, please?  The only other potential assertion I can see there is `sameAs` which I believe uses reference equality, which is not desired here.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the source, it looks like [this is the reason](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsUnit/blob/c1827fabad19544f2a5f98ee5f6732812d35f870/src/FsUnit.NUnit/Equality.fs#L21-L25):

`equal` for 'structural equatable' items like records and unions use the NUnit constraint:

```ml
Is.EqualTo(x).Or.EqualTo(x).Using<'T>(Equality.Structural)
```

And this constraint will feed into the error message.

Comment: I'm sure I checked that file... anyway, yes that's almost certainly it.

Comment: FYI - question edited to ask for a workaround as well as why.

Comment: @MarkPattison I'd guess the workaround is not to use this implementation. So that either means defining your own `equals` or submitting a PR to FsUnit to change it. Perhaps one option is to push the 'either' logic down into the custom comparer `Equality.Structural` (so it returns true if reference-equal *or* structure-equal) and change the constraint to simply `Is.EqualTo(x).Using<'T>(Equality.Structural)`. Though you'd have to check it's not used elsewhere!